# How to sort multiselected items?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, multi-select

I have already finished the function of grouping the selected items and unselected items, but I need to sort them in alphabetic order meanwhile.
My js code is shown below:

```
$("#id").multiselect({
    beforeopen: function (event, ui) {
        var selected = $("#id option:selected");
        selected.remove();
        $("#id").prepend(selected);
        $("#id").multiselect('refresh');
    }
});
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: could you share example output what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nice(-ish) way to do it:

```js
$("#clickity").click(function() {
    $("#derp>span").sort(function(a,b) {
        return (a.textContent || a.innerText).localeCompare(b.textContent || b.innerText);
    }).prependTo("#derp");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="derp"><span>g</span><span>o</span><span>t</span><span>h</span><span>s</span></div>
<button id="clickity">Sort!</button>
```

This will:

1. Find the matched elements (`span`s in this example, use your `:selected` selector for the real thing)
2. Sort the elements according to their `textContent` (or `innerText` for older browsers - it's more efficient this way than creating jQuery objects just to get the `.text()`)
3. Prepend them to the container again.

Note that you don't need to `.remove()` them, because appending (or in this case, prepending) an element somewhere actually moves it from its original location.

Comment: Hi, how can I get the selected items and unselected items in array?

Comment: @WillWang Depends what you need them in an array for. A jQuery object is already an array-like object, so...